# APC Not fetching although enabled - No error being shown

Tags: php, apc

I have APC installed and enabled on my website.  I wrote a little cache script and tested it on my development environment and it work.  When I moved it to our production server, it wasn't caching but it also wasn't throwing any errors.  I wrote a new test script to check to see what's going on and everything looks right.  Here's my test script:

```
//Do menu caching
$apc_fetch_status = false;
$dropdownmenu = apc_fetch('test',$apc_fetch_status);

print "<pre>";
print_r(apc_cache_info());
print "</pre>";

if (!$apc_fetch_status) {
    $dropdownmenu    = new stdClass();
    apc_store('test',$dropdownmenu,900);
    echo "no cache";
}else {
    echo "Cached!";
}

echo phpinfo();
```

When I run this script I show the following for apc_cache_info:

```
Array
(
    [num_slots] => 10243
    [ttl] => 0
    [num_hits] => 0
    [num_misses] => 1
    [num_inserts] => 1
    [expunges] => 0
    [start_time] => 1391716030
    [mem_size] => 4240
    [num_entries] => 1
    [file_upload_progress] => 1
    [memory_type] => mmap
    [locking_type] => pthread read/write Locks
    [cache_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => file
                    [device] => 0
                    [inode] => 0
                    [filename] => /home/xxx/public_html/test.php
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1391715986
                    [creation_time] => 1391716031
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1391716031
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 4240
                )
        )
    [deleted_list] => Array
        (
        )
    [slot_distribution] => Array
        (
            [1154] => 1
        )
)
```

Here is what phpinfo says about APC:

[image: PHP Info]

When I run this script I keep getting 'no cache' on each run showing me that it's not fetching my object.

Can anyone see anything in my setup that may be causing the fetch to fail?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you running the script from command line php?

Comment: I had not been.  I gave it a shot from the command line and am still getting the same results.

Comment: I was just checking because with command line php apc really doesn't work, in that the apc cache is created and discarded per process.

Comment: try setting the ttl value to 0.  Does it still not work?

Comment: Also, did you put apc.php in the webroot, so you could run it and take a look at what it's showing?

Comment: Setting the ttl to 0 didn't change anything.  I put apc.php at the webroot and it looks like everything is working.  I'm seeing apc.php in the system cache entries, but nothing for user entries.  Is there anything in particular I should be looking at?